# Converting Pendulum into Electricity?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I've been thinking about this, I want to use this as my science project.

The two viable solutions I've thought of so far are magnet or rotary based.

Pendulum clocks could be powered once a day and run the clock for the whole day. From the rotary motion, could I easily generate electricity?

A magnet on the pendulum could generate energy through coils.

Does anybody have any suggestions?
I'm just a highschool student so the project should be easy and small.

Any blueprints or tips will help. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this questions might be better suited for the engineering stack exchange, because the question is about how to make something that converts the motion of a pendulum into electricity and not about concepts of physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a good pendulum clock, you may be able to extract a minute amount of energy from it - but usually any additional friction will cause the clock to stop ticking. This is of course a function of the amount of energy you try to extract.

Here is the experiment to do:

Tape a strong disk magnet to the back of the pendulum. Make a coil of magnet wire with about 100 turns and the same diameter as the magnet (or a little bit bigger, but smaller than the amplitude of the pendulum swing). Tape the coil to a piece of cardboard, and put it behind the pendulum - close, but not touching.

Initially, leave the wires open (no closed circuit) and set the pendulum ticking. Confirm that it keeps going.

Now close the circuit - with a short circuit, or with a resistor of different sizes. I expect the pendulum will stop.

The experiment that you can now do is to see how long it takes the pendulum to be damped depending on the size of the resistor: this will give evidence that energy is extracted from the motion (if you do this with a free swinging pendulum the math is probably easier).

You can *try* to put a diode in series with the coil and use it to charge up a capacitor; with a high impedance digital multimeter you may be able to see the voltage build up.

Answer (score 0):

> A magnet on the pendulum could generate energy through coils.

It sure can, but the load would quickly bring the pendulum to a halt.

Pendulum clocks are a very careful balance of swinging mass, falling mass, springs, gears and escapement. It doesn't take much to upset the balance, and then the clock doesn't run.

The clock will run all day because the energy you put into it in the morning (by raising the weight or winding the spring) is *just* enough to run the mechanism until tomorrow. Clockmaking used to be a craft that took many years of apprenticeship to master, and even today it's not as simple as it looks.

Comment: I'm sure this is possible, so I'd rather do it with it's problems rather than throw it away. Clocks are very complex and sensitive, but I was just putting the only other way I could imagine.

Comment: Be aware that the energy which can be transferred from the weight to the pendulum on a single swing is very low. So the amount of energy which you can extract from the pendulum is also very low. You need to learn about escapement mechanisms. Basically, no, it is not possible.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - I think (see my answer) that the damping may be used as a way to demonstrate that energy is extracted... not quite the experiment originally conceived, but maybe a good one.